# How to check for user's first access to site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, forms-authentication

How can I check if a user accessed my website after his session expired? I set some Session values when the user logs in, but I just found out about a behavior that kinda messes with solution. I set those values when I log the user.

But what just happened is that I logged (social login) yesterday and closed the browser. Today when I accessed the site again I was already logged but my session had been finished, since I didn't have the values anymore.

So my question is: where does MVC4 checks if the user is logged or not? Can I attach an event handler to that action? Or add some filter like I do in Global.asax? Or is there a better approach to my problem? Is there a better way to add session values then the one I'm doing, or suggesting?

I read here [Where/how to populate session with user stored in cookie data in MVC app on first load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318223/where-how-to-populate-session-with-user-stored-in-cookie-data-in-mvc-app-on-firs) that session_start would be a place to start, although I don't wanna use the getter instantiate approach, since I only use Session's dictionary.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login state is stored in cookie. I usually take data from cookie in Global.asax and rebui,ld session there:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //take HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name here
            //and rebuild values in Session if session is empty
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware, that this approach will rebuild values in session even if they are not used later, but this should not be a problem in most websites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this method is called everytime the user access the website or only when authentication is needed?

Comment: @eestein: This method is executed with every request and that is why you check if user is not null.